# Running nodeJS app, selenium and webdriver.io tests in docker container

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do some webdriver.io tests with my node application, which is a docker image.

So what I did so far is:

1) Get *selenium server* by running this on my ubuntu server:

```
$ docker run -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

This gives me the running container 'ubuntu_selenium_1' (`$ docker ps`)

2) Build *node application* docker image, running node application in background and running e2e.js test file

In my gitlab-ci.yml I am doing

```
- docker build -t core:test -f Dockerfile.testing .
- docker run --rm core:test
```

That doesn't give me any output. No expected title and no error message.

So what am I doing wrong? There is a running selenium server, there is the node application which is loaded in background and the e2e.js test file is started.

I'm missing the connection of nodeJS app, webdriver and selenium...

**Dockerfile.testing**

```
FROM core:latest

# Copy the test files
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY e2e.js /

# Get npm packages AND install test framework - mocha and webdriver
RUN (cd programs/server && npm install --silent)
RUN npm install -g mocha --silent
RUN npm install chai webdriverio --silent
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

# Run application and then e2e test
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
node main.js & node e2e.js
```

Maybe this entrypoint script is wrong??

**e2e.js**

```
var     webdriverio = require('webdriverio'),
        options = {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            }
        }

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://localhost') // Which port do I have to use??
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title)
    })
    .end()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did what you need but I've separated the application to its own container.

You can try it yourself with my example here: https://github.com/xbx/webdriverio-docker-example

Here the changes:

First, add a `catch()` to your webdriverio instance:

```
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://app:3000')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title)
    })
    .catch(function(e){
      console.log('Error!')
      console.log(e)
    })
    .end()
```

Second, use `chrome` as browserName (must be, due to you're using selenium-chromium):

```
desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
```

Third, point correctly to your app:

```
.url('http://app:3000')
```

See how the containers are arranged:

```
version: "3"

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    links:
      - app
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  testing:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.testing
    command: /wait-for-it.sh selenium:4444 -- /wait-for-it.sh app:3000 -- node /e2e.js
    links:
      - app
      - selenium
    volumes:
      - ./wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
```

Running it: `docker-compose up --build`

```
Attaching to question_app_1, question_selenium_1, question_testing_1
app_1       | Started app.
selenium_1  | 12:19:45.516 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
...
selenium_1  | 12:19:45.769 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
testing_1   | Starting testing.
selenium_1  | 12:19:47.827 INFO - Executing: [get: http://app:3000])
app_1       | Hit!
selenium_1  | 12:19:48.210 INFO - Done: [get: http://app:3000]
selenium_1  | 12:19:48.220 INFO - Executing: [get title])
selenium_1  | 12:19:48.239 INFO - Done: [get title]
testing_1   | Title was: Hi, this is the title
```

---

Edit: simple change for docker-compose version 1:

```
testing:
    build:.
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.testing
    ......
    ......
```

Comment: That looks great. I'm not very familiar with docker compose, although I am using it. But I am using version 1. So selenium container is running and my own app container. But 'build' for testing container can't be used...

Comment: Running `docker-compose` gets stuck on `Building testing`. Nothing more on display and waiting... (What is `wait-for-it.sh` doing?)

Comment: wait-for-it is a post-build command to defer the execution of a program until the specified host:port is available. A build stuck could be because of a large project directory, is it your case?

Answer (score 1):

### webdriverio can't find selenium

You are invoking webdriverio like this:

```
var     webdriverio = require('webdriverio'),
        options = {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            }
        }
```

By default, it will attempt to use the selenium server on `localhost:4444`. However, that won't respond, because each container has its *own* localhost interface. Your selenium server is running in a different container.

You indicated in your question that your selenium container's name is `ubuntu_selenium_1`. So you can point webdriverio there. (container names can be used just like DNS hostnames.)

```
options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
    host: 'ubuntu_selenium_1',
    port: 4444
}
```

If your selenium container's name is something else, substitute that as the `host` parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem. I also tried to use `url('http://www.google.com')` in the test and only `node e2e.js` in the entrypoint.sh. But I don't get the website title as expected output.

Comment: What output do you get? Does `console.log` hello work?

Comment: @user3142695 I rewrote the answer entirely from earlier; see my new answer.

Comment: Is there a way for better debugging? Would like to see which host is used, so I should have seen that it was not / is correctly *ubuntu_selenium_1*... how can I check if the selenium server is running properly?

Comment: @Robert Yes it is working if it is outside of webdriverio.remote()... chain

Comment: @DanLowe I'm asking because I changed the host name, but still there is no output at all.